# How to check how much data flutter sends in API call?

Tags: flutter, dart, networking

I am using Visual Studio Code and DevTools but I cannot see how much data flutter sends in API call ?
In Devtools there is a Network tab but it only shows Header content length which is not representation of bytes.
I would like to see it in Bytes (mega, kilo, etc.). because it would be useful when sending Images / Videos to the backend.
Is there any way apart from starting wireshark or usage on my router ?

Comment: Have a look at the package:https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_stetho

Comment: @JoyTerence well, it does not support newest flutter version 1.23 have a look here - https://github.com/brianegan/flutter_stetho/issues/42